# Pandas: Calculate the average over all of the columns for n rolling rows at a time

Tags: python, pandas

What I am trying to do is this... I have time series and I want to calculate rolling average, for n rows across multiple columns. 
What I did initially was to make another column that would contain average for each row and then do your standard rolling average for n rows.
However, when I don't have values in some of the columns that throws off my calculations.

Example:

```
Col1 | Col2 | Col3 | Avg
10   | 20   |      | 15
     | 10   |      | 10
10   | 15   |  20  | 15
```

Rolling average of Avg: `13.33`

While it should be: `14.16`

Here is the example that worked for me that has all the numbers...

```
Col1 | Col2 | Col3 | Avg 
10   | 20   |   15 | 15
10   | 10   |   10 | 10
10   | 15   |   20 | 15
```

Rolling average of Avg: `13.33`

While it should be: `13.33`

What I can do is a manual loop... I also can add second column that would contain number of elements in each row.

But is there a better way to do it?

Comment: I don't understand where 12.14 comes from?

Comment: If you add all values available in first example and divide them, you will get 12.14

Comment: 10+20+10+10+15+20 / 6 = 12.14

Comment: That's what I mean `(10+20+10+10+15+20) / 6 != 12.14`

Comment: darn it... you are right, it is 14.16. I guess I copy/paste wrong value.

Comment: corrected my question. thank you

Answer (score 0):

`np.nanmean` will average everything in a multi-dimensional array.

```
np.nanmean(df.values)

14.166666666666666
```

Using this in a rolling 3 periods fashion, you could do this

```
pd.Series({df.index[i]: np.nanmean(df.iloc[i-2:i+1].values) for i in range(2, len(df))})

2    14.166667
dtype: float64
```

---

Comment: Thank you! Actually that's what I have done, but it felt too "manual". I was hoping for more elegant way without having to rely on iloc and looping through.